# Regarding time format change in Wdcalendar?

Tags: jquery

In month view dateshow returns the value "Mar 7 (Wed)".
In week view dateshow returns the value "Mar 7 (Wed) 15:00 -  16:00".
I couldn't understand how this value changes depending on the view.

```
var dateshow = CalDateShow(start, end, !isallday, true);


function CalDateShow(startday, endday, isshowtime, isshowweek) {
        if (!endday) {
            return dateFormat.call(startday, getymformat(startday,null,isshowtime));
        } else {
            var strstart= dateFormat.call(startday, getymformat(startday, null, isshowtime, isshowweek));
            var strend=dateFormat.call(endday, getymformat(endday, startday, isshowtime, isshowweek));
            var join = (strend!=""? " - ":"");
            return [strstart,strend].join(join);
        }
    }
```

Reference: [I downloaded this plug in from this link only.](http://www.web-delicious.com/jquery-plugins-demo/wdCalendar/sample.php)

I'm really need to know about it. Moreover I'm in a hurray. So, please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

This method is not where the format of the date being displayed is decided. The actual method deciding the format is the getymformat(). so, any changes should go there.

Based on the value being passed for isshowtime, the gettymformat will return a

```
function getymformat(date, comparedate, isshowtime, isshowweek, showcompare) {
...            
a.push(showweek ? " (W)" : "", showtime ? " HH:mm" : "");
return a.join("");
}
```

For the month view, **showtime** will be *false*, leaving you with only the *Month Date (Day)* format that is set in the code already.
For the week view, **showtime** will be *true*, leaving you with the Date format as *Month Date (Day) + HH:mm*